# EDI X12 810 Document

Tags: document, edi, x12, invoices

Where can I find a sample document with multiple invoices in the same 810 document? Most of the samples I find only has one invoice.

Answer (score 1):

Safeway has an example that has two invoices in it:

[Safeway 810 004030 Sample](http://suppliers.safeway.com/usa/doc/810-X12-004030Sample.doc)

If you have a translator, it might be a worthwhile exercise to create an outbound 810 map for the purpose of generating your own test data. I have had to do that on many occasions when my trading partners weren't really ready or provided test data that I thought was inadequate for exercising all the functions of our process.

Answer (score 1):

try this for safeway:

http://suppliers.safeway.com/usa/edi_us/edi_mapping.asp